# Javascript Affecting the Wrong Element

Tags: javascript, html

I am setting up a webpage so that it has multiple images on it, and each image has a 50% opacity mask over it. When the mask is moused over, it is supposed to disappear, and then when the mouse leaves the image (below the mask), the mask is supposed to reappear. This worked well when I tested it for one `img` inside my `div`, but when I added a second `img`, the disappear function affected the image with no `id`, which is confusing me greatly.

HTML:

```
<div id="images">
    <img id="testimage1" src="url" onmouseover="appear1()"/>
    <img src="url"/>
</div>
<div id="masks">
    <img id="testmask1" src="url" onmouseover="disappear1()"/>
    <img src="url"/> <!-- This is the one that disappears -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#images{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
#masks{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
}
```

JS:

```
function disappear1(){
    //Makes the first test mask disappear. This is a test function.
    document.getElementById("testmask1").style.display = 'none';
}

function appear1(){
    //Makes the first test mask appear. This is a test function.
    document.getElementById("testmask1").style.display = 'block';
}
```

EDIT: Roko asked why I didn't do this in pure CSS. Aside from the fact that I didn't think about how to configure the images correctly, when I eventually finish this page, I will want to have masks 'linked', where I mouse over one mask and both disappear. I'm not sure that's possible in pure CSS.

EDIT #2: As it turns out, the function was working as written. It was just that because I had a single `div` for each row of images, when the first image in the row appeared, everything else slid over, thus poor coding on my part.

Comment: There are two images with no `id`. Which one?

Comment: The second one in `#masks`. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't duplicate your `ID`. ID should be unique-per-page.
Also, why not do it in pure CSS? (**no JS required**)

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/poyamu/1/edit?html,css,output)***

```
<div class="imgBox">
    <img src="cat.jpg">
    <img src="mask.png">
</div>
<div class="imgBox">
    <img src="bear.jpg">
    <img src="mask.png">
</div>
<div class="imgBox">
    <img src="elephant.jpg">
    <img src="mask.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.imgBox{
  position:relative;
  /*width, height etc... */
}
.imgBox img{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: opacity 0.5s; /* yey! */
}
.imgBox:hover img + img{ /* on hover target the second image */
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: The most relevant reason is because when I finish the page, I'll have images referring to the same thing in different places. In your example, if I mouse over 'elephant' or 'cat', the mask over both disappears. I can't think how to do that in CSS.

Comment: @Aliden if that *other triggers* are distant in the document, than you need JS I'm afraid. But it's really easy. Assign an hover event handler for all those elements, grab some `data-*` attribute that will refer to the desired mask element (by some number or else)

Comment: The other triggers are going to be images in other `imgBox`es, if you will. Your comment is going over my head, particularly the `data-*` part. If you could point me at a link that discusses it or clarify a bit, I'd appreciate it.